# JOptionPane window opens in background

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am developing a swing application, just a little query about `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` which is bugging me:

- `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record entered successfully");`
  If i write this code the Message window appears at the back  of my parent frame.
- `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record entered successfully");`
  whereas this code automatically places the window over the parent frame.

The question is: while implementing **`null`** as the first argument i get the message at the background of current parent frame whereas if i write **`this`** as the first argument the window comes over the parent frame. Why is this happenning?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: When "owned" by a window, the dialog will appear above it and will block it.  That's how they work

Comment: The question is : while implementing **`null`** as the first argument i get the message at the background of current parent frame whereas if i write **`this`** as the first argument the window comes over the parent frame. WHY IS THIS HAPPENING?

Comment: @MadProgrammer : by "owned" do you mean using `this`?

Comment: As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29) states, the first parameter determines the parent frame. The dialog is placed over that when it's specified (ie. the case where you pass `this` as the argument). If the parent is not specified, the results are somewhat system dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method

```
showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message)
```

the first argument sets the parent of the dialog:

> parentComponent
>
> Defines the Component that is to be the parent of this dialog box. It is used in two ways: the Frame that contains it is used as the Frame parent for the dialog box, and its screen coordinates are used in the placement of the dialog box. In general, the dialog box is placed just below the component. This parameter may be `null`, in which case a default Frame is used as the parent, and the dialog will be centered on the screen (depending on the L&F).

I assume that the method appears inside a `JFrame` class, in which case passing `this` as the argument will set the parent component as that frame.

Answer (score 0):

The java keyword `this` is used (in this case) to refer to the current class - so you're referring to your parent window. See this link, It's pretty handy:

http://javapapers.com/core-java/explain-the-java-this-keyword/